# Function param default value std:vector initialization with Rcpp and C++11?

Tags: r, c++11, rcpp

I am trying to write a C++/Rcpp function that has an optional argument whos default needs to be  a vector of length 1 with a value of 0. The following does not compile properly:

```
cppFunction("std::vector<int> test(std::vector<int> out = {0}) {
  return out;
}")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in cppFunction("std::vector test(std::vector out =
>   {1}) {\n  return out;\n}") :    No function definition found In
>   addition: Warning messages: 1: No function found for Rcpp::export
>   attribute at fileee5f629605d7.cpp:5  2: In sourceCpp(code = code, env
>   = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  :   No Rcpp::export attributes or RCPP_MODULE declarations found in source

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was posted on the Rcpp issue tracker. This is the desired result that I wanted just not with std::vector.

```
cppFunction("IntegerVector test(IntegerVector out = IntegerVector::create(0)) {
   return out;
}")
```

Comment: You can trivially cast that so that what is created as a `Rcpp::IntegerVector` gets returned as `std::vector<int>`.  Rcpp makes the conversion automatically for you.

Comment: Well the only reason I am using std::vector in the first place is because inside the function I need to grow/fill that vector to match the length of another vector. Does IntegerVector have an equivalent to resize()? EDIT: I would up vote this answer but I supplied it.

Comment: Which vector type to use when has been discussed numerous times here and on the rcpp-devel list.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the underlying C++ function in an R function that uses a default value:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> cpp_test(const std::vector<int>& x)
{
  return x;
}

/*** R

test <- function(X = c(0L))
{
  cpp_test(X)
}

test()

test(c(1:5))

*/
```

which gives you

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/RcppFiles/cpp_test.cpp')
> test()
[1] 0

> test(c(1:5))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: This is what I used to do. However, compileAttributes() trashes any changes made in RcppExports.R. I am trying to only maintain one file (the cpp file).

Comment: Just use a second R file. Call your autogenerated `foo_impl()` and have `foo()` call `foo_impl()` with the trick shown here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, using your trick woudl leave `foo_impl()` documented and `foo()` undocumented. The documented `foo_impl()` would also not show the default args. This solves the issue of having the changes to RcppExports. R being trashed but does not address the main goal of only having to maintain the code and docs in one file (which is why most people use roxygen).

Comment: @RyanHope I am not sure I follow--whether or not you document `foo()` (by hand or via roxygen) is fully under your control.  Similarly, you are not forced to use Attributes and hence have your `foo_impl()` automatically visible.

Comment: I want to be able to edit 1 file with code and docs. So for example, I have test.cpp with my documented test() function. compileAttributes() generates RcppExports.cpp and RcppExports.R. The former would suck to have to construct manually, the documentation from test.cpp is now injected into RcppExports.R and this is where Roxygen gets its help info about test(). Now, if I have to create a second file that is a wrapper to test() just so that I can set a default argument then now I have to manually document test_wrap() which is what I am trying to avoid by using compileAttributes().

Comment: Well if it "sucks" so badly then maybe Rcpp is not for you. Sorry. Not everything can be done in a one-file solution, and as you also supplied this on GitHub (though everybody knows that crossposting sucks worse) I followed up there. Your example ain't working.

Comment: don't put words in my mouth, "sucks" was your word not mine

Comment: Your words exactly:  "The former would suck".  That is from your comment two steps up in the comment timeline here.

Comment: Also, you seem to be very focused on your desired one-file solution. And `sourceCpp()` and `cppFunction()` are very nice and powerful, but we have explained *numerous times* that your goal should be *a package* in which case many of your complaints become entirely moot.  I suggest you read up a little, maybe starting with the Rcpp Attributes vignette and then come back with questions if you have any.  And preferably ask on only the rcpp-list rather than here and on GitHub.

Comment: Maybe part of the confusion here was my use of cppFunction as a minimal working example. All of this code is in an R package that I am developing. I am not using cppFunction or sourceCpp in my actual code.

Comment: Piling up options here instead of useless vocabulary battles; I'm planning to extend how to give defaults in the `attributes` package, which is compatible with Rcpp and other implementations of R/C++.  https://github.com/Rcpp11/attributes/issues/36

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `Rcpp` package didn't support the exporting the default values. There are several packages to improve this (including `Rcpp11`), thought, I have a solution on `Rcpp` with [`RCPP_MODULES`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf):

```
library("Rcpp")

cppFunction(plugins=c("cpp11"),'NumericVector test(std::vector<int> out) {
  return wrap(out);
}

RCPP_MODULE(mod) {
  function("test",&test,List::create( _["out"] = std::vector<int>({0})), "Simple description");
}', verbose=TRUE,rebuild=TRUE)
```

I change the return type, thought, it work even if you return `std::vector<int>`.

So, how this works: it just creates a documentation entry with the default value, third argument for `RCPP_MODULES`.

With just `{0}` my `R` crashes, so, it's necessary for me to put `std::vector` explicitly.

Comment: Actually, Rcpp does export default values. It just doesn't seem to work with primitive types.

Comment: What Rcpp does is to convert the rhs of `=` into R code. It only know how to deal with certain things. I'm experimenting with an alternative way to set the formals of the R function with R code in the attributes package. https://github.com/Rcpp11/attributes/issues/36